# Using Jekyll, how to effectively store code samples?

Tags: jekyll

I'm in a bit of a pickle. I have a website on GitHub Pages, (re)generated using Jekyll. A number of pages on this website reference a set of code snippets stored in a subdirectory (say, `/src/`). I want

- to somehow *include* (as in `{% include %}`) those code snippets to each of the pages so I don't have to maintain multiple copies (in case the snippets are just copy-pasted to the pages),
- the snippets to persist through the generation of static pages (which, I assume, excludes putting them somewhere under `_includes`/`_posts`).

The best I did was putting them into a separate directory under `_posts` and then using `{% include_relative %}`, but the files don't make it to `_site` that way.

So, could please somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

You can use GitHub Gists to embed the code.

This will look like that:

`file.md`:

```
Content

<script src="https://gist.github.com/VirtuaCreative/a219a7dca80f12434d1b.js"></script>

Content
```

View how does it looks like on my "test" project on GitHub: http://github.virtuacreative.com.br/test/2016/welcome-to-jekyll1/

From there, you'll have the code block and the `raw` button.

To do that, just go to https://gist.github.com/ and add a new gist. You can add a description and name the file with its right extension.

This would be the fastest way. But I'm not sure if this will achieve what you need.

Comment: This is very nice, but I would really like to keep the files in the same repository. I really appreciate your effort, but I see there apparently is no easy way to meet my needs using Jekyll. I really hope your suggestions work for someone else. Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps another STO user can come forward with a better answer, hopefully. :) but there's that way I told you about, using data and collections, but it would duplicate the code, I'm afraid. Anyway, best of luck for you! :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

This answer doesn't satisfy the needs of the question's author, but might be useful for someone else, that's why I'm keeping it here.

---

You'd better use collections, so you can call a collection of `markdown` files into a single html page.

For example:

1st. Add collections to your `_config.yml` file (let's say the name for your collection is `snippets`):

```
collections:
  snippets:
    permalink: /snippets/:path/
```

2nd. Now create a folder called `_snippets` in the site root.

3rd. Then create a html page from where you'll call that collection:

```
{% for snippet in site.snippets %} ... {% endfor %}
```

Then all snippets will be displayed on that page according to your markup.

If you want to group the snippets, for example, "javascript", "php", "css", you can add a collection to each of them and call them in different html pages:

1st. `_config.yml`:

```
collections:
  javascript:
    permalink: /snippets/javascript/:path/ # this is just an example 
  php:
    permalink: /snippets/php/:path/ # this is just an example 
  css:
    permalink: /snippets/css/:path/ # this is just an example
```

2nd. Create folders: `_javascript`, `_php` and `_css`

3rd. Create your markdown files within the folders:

````
---
layout: whatever
title: My first snippet
...
---

```javascript
<script>
var car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = car.type;
</script>
```
````

Then call them within a html page or multiple pages, it's up to you how to organize them:

```
{% for snippet in site.javascript %} 
...
<h1>{{ snippet.title }}</h1>
<div>
  {{ snippet.content }}
</div>
... 
{% endfor %}
```

Then do the same for the others:

```
{% for snippet in site.php %} ... {% endfor %}
{% for snippet in site.css %} ... {% endfor %}
```

Hope to have helped! :)

Comment: Am I right assuming that each file in the collection has to have a "front matter"? Because it doesn't seem acceptable for .cpp files I'm working on. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Yes, they are like markdown posts, but they don't live in the `_posts` directory. But the only front-matter you need is the layout. Perhaps, if you don't need any layout at all it can be set to null `layout: null`

Comment: I've never heard anything about `.ccp` files with Jekyll, you mean .ccp code blocks? I thought you just wanted to display code blocks. Perhaps you can try [Jekyll data](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/) instead of collections.

Comment: Yeah, I want a set of .cpp files to be `{% include %}`able in the posts and copied to the output (so I can reference them via a link). No front matter/etc. is allowed, because I also want users to be able to compile them. I'm not sure how data would help here, can you please explain this a bit?

Comment: You mean as a code block (on the post) or as a link to a raw file or both?

Comment: Both, if that's possible.

Comment: What about using [Codepen](http://codepen.io/) for this? Like [this post](https://css-tricks.com/posting-code-blocks-wordpress-site/) does.

Comment: But you could do that without Codepen, with collections + data. On the collections you display the code and add a button to view the raw. On this button, you'd add a link to the raw file. This link would be stored in a data `.yml` file.

Comment: That means that I would have to duplicate the code, placing it both in the collection and in a separate file, right? Or doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid you would. I mean, in a markdown file you'd have the display view. And you'd have a `file.ccp` stored in a separate folder, untouched by Jekyll. Unless you don't want to display it. Then just Jekyll data would do the job.

Comment: Perhaps would be a better way out. Let me think about it.

Comment: Ok, I'll add another answer with a suggestion. Let's see if you like it. I'll keep this answer where we are commenting on as it might be usefull for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/) is a nice way to maintain code snippets in one place, as suggested by @Virtua Creative. And, I [see](https://demisx.github.io/jekyll/2014/01/13/improve-code-highlighting-in-jekyll.html#option-2-via-embedded-github-gists) that GitHub Gists are supported already, like `{% gist [gist_number] %}`.

But if you want to maintain code files within your Jekyll project, try this plugin: [remote_file_content](https://github.com/dimitri-koenig/jekyll-plugins).

Once installed, it is easy to use. Below snippet is from the plugin's GitHub page.

```
{% highlight javascript tabsize=4 %}
{% remote_file_content /src/your-snippet.html %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If like me you're using a command line tool to generate code-snippet html includes should work fine.

Create a `_includes/code-snippets` directory then reference the files using a normal includes splash tag.

```
<figure>
{% include code-snippets/big-test.html %}
<figcaption>Bad: Three different scenarios bundled in to one test</figcaption>
</figure>
```